# Cannot start KVM machine on arch after update

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, updates, qemu, linux-kvm

I'm having trouble with a VM I was using yesterday. After using, I closed the guest and updated my host machine (arch linux). Today I turned on the host and tried to turn on my guest and this message appears:

> Error starting domain: unsupported configuration: chardev 'spicevmc'
> not supported without spice graphics
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in
> cb_wrapper
> callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 108, in tmpcb
> callback(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line
> 57, in newfn
> ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1384, in
> startup
> self._backend.create()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1352, in create
> raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed') libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: chardev 'spicevmc'
> not supported without spice graphics

I'm using a dedicated nvidia card on a manjaro guest OS.

**I'm not a linux expert.**

Any idea what might be happening and how to fix this?

Any other info you need let me know.

**UPDATE #1:**

I removed the usb spice redirectors from my VM:

```
<redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
  <address type="usb" bus="0" port="4"/>
</redirdev>
<redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
  <address type="usb" bus="0" port="5"/>
</redirdev>
```

And now it works fine... I just can't have usb redirectors on the guest OS now... Anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was based off a couple of the answers above.
Basically in order to have the "Channel Spice" device (used for things like redirecting individual USB devices, I think),  I ended up with the following:

- a "Display Spice" device (Spice Server)
- a "Video" device set to "None"
- and my Spice Channel (which was the one I wanted, but was throwing errors)

Screen shots and XML of each device below.

[ScreenShot of Display Spice Device (Virtual Machine Manager)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHNn5.png)

```
<graphics type="spice" port="5901" autoport="yes" listen="127.0.0.1">

  <listen type="address" address="127.0.0.1"/>

  <image compression="off"/>

  <gl enable="no"/>

</graphics>
```

[ScreenShot of Video Device (Virtual Machine Manager)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WdjW.png)

```
<video>

  <model type="none"/>

  <alias name="video0"/>

</video>
```

[ScreenShot of Spice Channel Device (Virtual Machine Manager)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX2LQ.png)

```
  <target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0" state="disconnected"/>

  <alias name="channel0"/>

  <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>

</channel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my VM too does this fix work with evdev?

update:
I can't even remove the:

```
<redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
  <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
</redirdev>
<redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
  <address type="usb" bus="0" port="2"/>
</redirdev>
```

It spits out the same error

update 2:
My VM boots after I added spice server and set the video to none

Answer (score 0):

same I was able to use virsh edit to remove the two spice redirectors and everything works fine now but I'm not sure what they were used for

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, I tried adding a spice server which caused some issues with mutiple monitors, like the mouse sticking to one of the displays. I removed "Channel Spice" and it let me start the VM without spice graphics. I removed these lines from the XML in virt-manager.

```
<channel type="spicevmc">
  <target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0"/>
  <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
</channel>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue after the recent ArchLinux upgrade.
Simply adding a Spice display server (which defaults to a new cirrus display) will stop my VM from booting, because it's taking over the main console, and the nvidia passthrough will stop working.
The workaround is to first add a Spice display server, and then change the Video type to 'None'.

[image: Video_None]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is your answer better than the other ones? If you only wanted to add the image, propose an edit to the existing answer.